# Freeform Form Not Submitting

Tags: solspace-freeform

For some reason forms have stopped submitting on a site we manage. I have created a test form with the below code and it also does not submit. I don't see any errors. EE 2.9 and FF 4.1.7. Any ideas what to check?

```
{exp:freeform:form form_id="2" return="contact/thank_you" notify="redacted"}
    <div>
        <label>{freeform:label:name}                                
          {freeform:field:name}
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>   
          {freeform:submit}
      </div>
    </div>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all looks good except for this parameter: `notify="redacted"`
I'm not sure what that means.
Take a look at the parameters for notification override settings https://solspace.com/expressionengine/legacy/freeform-4/form/#admin_notify
You can set most of those in the forms settings as well and won'tneed the parameters.

Comment: I redacted my email address from the parameter for privacy, is what that means. Thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned, "notify" is not a usable parameter. Check out the available notify parameters in the docs. Try turning on template debug along with php errors and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I didn't read your answer well enough the first time. I removed all of the parameters and it appears to be submitting now, although I have a new error appearing: "You are not authorized to perform this action - Reason: Banned"

Comment: Make sure you are completely logged out, and try again. That's an EE security message. Then if you are logged in, check your user status.